# Need more information on this! aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, gcc, memory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRING_LEN 80
#define ARRAY_LEN 10000

void *emalloc(size_t s) {
    void *result = malloc(s);
    if (NULL == result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed! \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    char word[STRING_LEN];
    char *wordlist[ARRAY_LEN];
    int num_words;
    int i;
    num_words = 0;
    while (num_words < ARRAY_LEN && scanf("%79s", word)) {
        wordlist[num_words] = emalloc((strlen(word) + 1) * sizeof wordlist[0][0]);
        strcpy(wordlist[num_words], word);
        num_words++;
    }

    sort_words(wordlist, num_words);
    for (i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", wordlist[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
        free(wordlist[i]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void sort_words(char **w, int n) {
    int i;
    int j;
    char *key;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        key = w[i];
        for (j = i - 1; j > 0; j--) {
            if (strcmp(w[j], key) > 0) {
                w[j + 1] = w[j];
            } else {
                w[j + 1] = key;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program is basically for taking in words and sorting them.

When I run this using `gcc -W -Wall -O2 -ansi -pedantic -g words_sorted.c -o ws`, I get a huge stack trace and it says core dumped.
I am taking input from a file **randwords.txt** and redirecting the input using `./ws < randwords`

this is the memory map after the output

```
** Error in `./ws': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000002443030 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x791fb)[0x7f844f2281fb]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x8288a)[0x7f844f23188a]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f844f2352bc]
./ws[0x400756]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7f844f1cf401]
./ws[0x4007ba]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:2e 86686535                           /home/cshome/s/skarmakar/242/lab05/ws
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 00:2e 86686535                           /home/cshome/s/skarmakar/242/lab05/ws
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 00:2e 86686535                           /home/cshome/s/skarmakar/242/lab05/ws
02443000-024a6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f8448000000-7f8448021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f8448021000-7f844c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f844ef98000-7f844efae000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 67160174                   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-6.3.1-20161221.so.1
7f844efae000-7f844f1ad000 ---p 00016000 08:02 67160174                   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-6.3.1-20161221.so.1
7f844f1ad000-7f844f1ae000 r--p 00015000 08:02 67160174                   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-6.3.1-20161221.so.1
7f844f1ae000-7f844f1af000 rw-p 00016000 08:02 67160174                   /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-6.3.1-20161221.so.1
7f844f1af000-7f844f36c000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 67232076                   /usr/lib64/libc-2.24.so
7f844f36c000-7f844f56b000 ---p 001bd000 08:02 67232076                   /usr/lib64/libc-2.24.so
7f844f56b000-7f844f56f000 r--p 001bc000 08:02 67232076                   /usr/lib64/libc-2.24.so
7f844f56f000-7f844f571000 rw-p 001c0000 08:02 67232076                   /usr/lib64/libc-2.24.so
7f844f571000-7f844f575000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f844f575000-7f844f59a000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 67232069                   /usr/lib64/ld-2.24.so
7f844f67f000-7f844f782000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f844f797000-7f844f79a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f844f79a000-7f844f79b000 r--p 00025000 08:02 67232069                   /usr/lib64/ld-2.24.so
7f844f79b000-7f844f79c000 rw-p 00026000 08:02 67232069                   /usr/lib64/ld-2.24.so
7f844f79c000-7f844f79d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffd62698000-7ffd626b9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffd6277c000-7ffd6277e000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffd6277e000-7ffd62780000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Please help! Output is okayish but something is not right. The code is sorting the words properly but I want to know why this backtrace and core dumped message is displayed and get rid of it!

Comment: I am pretty sure something is wrong with your sort function. Try to input `CCC BBB AAA` (split by newline): https://ideone.com/tWXhdR#stdin

Comment: Use a debugger. Note that `scanf` returns *`EOF`* if your file doesn't end with whitespace. It is non-zero.

Comment: Show full output. And try without sorting.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong above, of course `%s` can never have a matching failure, hence `scanf` will **never** return a false value and you scan garbage for the whole length of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- The loop test does not check for proper `scanf()` conversion. At end of file, `scanf()` returns `EOF` which is not `0`. The test should be

  ```
  while (num_words < ARRAY_LEN && scanf("%79s", word) == 1)
  ```
- The `sort_words` function has a flaw: if the first entry is larger than `key`, it is duplicated in `w[1]` but `key` is not stored into `w[0]`. Hence the sort is incorrect and the first entry is freed twice, which produces the error trace.

  You can easily fix the code this way:

  ```
  void sort_words(char **w, int n) {
      int i, j;
      char *key;

      for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
          key = w[i];
          for (j = i - 1; j > 0 && strcmp(w[j], key) > 0; j--) {
              w[j + 1] = w[j];
              w[j] = key;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with your `void sort_words(char **w, int n)` function.

1. String copy is `c` is using function `strcpy()` not using `=` . statements like `key  = w[i];` should be replaced by `strcpy(key, w[i]);`.
2. You have to allocate memory for key either by `char key[STRING_LEN];` or using `malloc()`.
3. Your sorting logic may not work. I have replaced it with `Bubble-Sort` logic.

Try this modified function :-

```
void sort_words(char **w, int n)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    char key[STRING_LEN];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(w[j], w[j + 1]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(key, w[j + 1]);
                strcpy(w[j + 1], w[j]);
                strcpy(w[j], key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid your solution is incorrect: if the space allocated for `w[j]` and `w[j + 1]` have a different size, the second or third `strcpy` will have undefined behavior.